# want user defined header for query result stored in data frame in python

Tags: python

```py
import pandas as pd      
check = "select distinct(region) from Tablename" 
HiveDF = hc.sql(check)
check=HiveDF.toPandas()
```

I just want to add header "Name" to the query result
Output as below is needed

| Name |
| --- |
| NAM |
| AsiA |
| Europe |

Comment: Please show an example of what that result would look like. For example, do you want the column header returned from the table as well? Do you want to define the name of the column the returned data is placed into? It's unclear from your explanation.